# Unable to connect via SSH from my PC

Tags: server, ssh, vps, sshd

I am having problems to connect a Linose server via SSH from my ubuntu console. **I can connect from other PC's to the same server**.

When I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
ssh stop/waiting
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Everything seem to be good, but

```
$ sudo service sshd
sshd: unrecognized service
```

And when I try to connect my server:

```
ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I get timed out message.

I have tried uninstall and reinstall, but I am getting the same message.
I also tried:

```
$ ssh localhost
```

And everything works fine.

**EDIT**
Results for `ssh -vvv root@xx.xx.xx.xx`

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 45.33.12.79 [45.33.12.79] port 22.
```

**UPDATE**
I ran:

```
$ sudo lsof -i | grep ssh
sshd      12020    root    3u  IPv4 125114      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd      12020    root    4u  IPv6 125116      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

And:

```
$ netstat -l --numeric-ports | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

...
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
...
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes
...
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: Inactive
```

Comment: Where did you try to install the openssh-server? On your local machine or on the server?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin On my local machine. As I said, I can connect to the server via SSH from other PC's, I am having problems only from my PC

Comment: Post results of 'ssh -vvv root@whatever'

Comment: @wlraider70 updated.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think this flavor uses the daemon end part. I think your service name is ssh-service. I may be wrong on that though.
2. Your firewall may be filtering out port 22.

Do a port scan on your machine and check to see if 22 is open.

**Edit**

Okay - now - check your SSH config is listening on 22. I still think that it's not sshd, it's something else. Service ssh status or something of the sort. Haven't worked on that flavor in a long time.

Next - do you have a firewall in between? Try turning off iptables if you have it on. Fail2ban? These all can cause problems. Go into ash config and ensure password authentication is on if you are just trying to connect without any certificates or real security.

**Edit again**

I would say that there is some type of firewall rule or corrupt IPtable rule on your host box then if others can connect to the server. I have seen this more times than you can believe. Run a flush on iptables on the host. (Can you even ping the server machine?)

That's the old viable reason at this point since ssh localhost works.

**Edit again again**

Iptables isn't a service.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated, can you check results, please?

Comment: Updated, i will uncomment the last line. --> Didn't work

Comment: I can ping the server's IP, I when I run `service iptables stop` I get `iptables: unrecognized service`

Comment: Iptables isn't a service. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html

Comment: Done, the same problem...

Comment: Timed out is 99% usually a firewall filtration. If something was wrong with the service or install package you'd get an immediate deny.

Comment: How can I check if there's firewall blocking? I ran: `nc -vz localhost 22` and get `Connection to localhost 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!`

Comment: Please, see last update.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to me like a problem with permission on folder (and files recursive) /home/user/.ssh/

You want this folder (.ssh) and all files underneath , to be protected from anyone (except you of course). So change the permission in this folder (and to all files underneath) with chmod command .

Sudo chmod 600 ~./ssh

The number is a permission setting, I think 600 will solve the problem, which I believe stems from too permissive of a file.

above command will remove the Read , Write and Execute permission from Everyone , except the owner of the folder (and files inside it) which in this case is You.

Comment: On my local machine? I did it but still getting timed out message.

Comment: On the machine connecting. the client not the server

Comment: I did. I didn't work.